# ASP.NET MVC Action Call from Javascript AJAX Receives 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, iis-7.5

Receiving a '500 Internal Server Error' message when using ajax to call controller action in server with IIS 7.5 web site. Process works fine in localhost development environment.

The process involves an Ajax call that sends a json object to the controller action method which then sends back a json message. I've already tried creating a custom route in the Routeconfig file to take into account the iis site name. IE, "http://localhost:3000/home" vs "http://{SiteName}/{defaultapplicationpage}.

JS File

```
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            type: "POST",
            url: "/TimeEntryWeeklyReportsTest/Home/CheckIfRecordsExist",
            //url: "/Home/CheckIfRecordsExist",
            data: '{ data:' + jsondata + '}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json"
        }).done(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            if (response === "true") {
                var param = "&StartDate=" + data.StartDate + "&EndDate=" + data.EndDate;
                param = Employeefilter !== undefined ? param + "&" + Employeefilter + "=" + data.EmployeeUserid : param + "&Employee=" + data.EmployeeUserid;
                $('#successmsg').html("Successful");
                window.location.href = url + param + "&rs:Format=" + documentType;
            }
            else {
                $('#errmsg').html("No records found.");
                throw 'records not found error';
            }
        }).fail(function (response) {
            console.log('Error: ' + response);
        });
```

CS Controller

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("TimeEntryWeeklyReportsTest/Home/CheckIfRecordsExist")]
        public JsonResult CheckIfRecordsExist(FormData data)
        {
            string strID = GetIDFromUser((!String.IsNullOrEmpty(GetUser())) ? GetUser() : Environment.UserName);
            var results = timeEntry.TimeEntryReport(data.EmployeeSupervisor == "Supervisor" ? null : data.EmployeeUserid, data.EmployeeSupervisor == "Employee" ? null : data.EmployeeUserid, Convert.ToDateTime(data.Startdate), Convert.ToDateTime(data.Enddate)).ToList<TimeEntryReport_Result>();
            if (results.Count != 0)
            {
                return Json("true", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            else
            {
                return Json("false", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

RouteConfig

```
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "CheckIfRecordsExist",
                url: "TimeEntryWeeklyReportsTest/{controller}/{action}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "CheckIfRecordsExist" }
            );
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

The expected Result is to have the method return either a "true" or "false" statement. It seems that the ajax call is not handled and a 500 internal error is received.

Comment: The details of that 500 error are very important. From the client perspective, 500 literally just means "something went wrong on the server." Those details don't usually go to the client because the user doesn't need to know. But if you debug on the server you can see what the actual exception is, and that will be a first step toward fixing it. If you can't find it while debugging, you might also be able to find it in Event Viewer.

Comment: Agree with Scott's suggestion. Additionally, if you have implemented error handling, try to place a beak-point there. Also, for a quick check, add try catch block in the controller, just for testing.

Comment: Also, aside from the above, remove `async: false`. It's very bad practice and you don't need it as you've implemented promise callbacks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try in your controller like this to serv json and used that in javascript

```
 public async Task<JsonResult> DonutChartData()
        {
            int tagIn = (await db.Tag.Where(x => x.IsIn == true).ToListAsync()).Count;
            int cardIn = (await db.Entry.Where(c => c.Type == Type.Card).Where(x => x.IsExit == false).ToListAsync()).Count;
            int reservedIn = (await db.Cars.Where(c => c.Type == Type.Pin).Where(x => x.IsExit == false).ToListAsync()).Count;
            DonutChart _chart = new DonutChart();
            _chart.labels = new string[] { "x", "y", "x" };
            _chart.datasets = new List<DonutChartDatasets>();
            List<DonutChartDatasets> _dataSet = new List<DonutChartDatasets>();
            _dataSet.Add(new DonutChartDatasets()
            {
                label = "Whois",
                //TO-DO: Add Reserve to Report
                data = new int[] { cardIn, tagIn, reservedIn },
                backgroundColor = new string[] { "rgba(54, 162, 235,0.5)", "rgba(255, 205, 86,0.5)", "rgba(255,99,132,0.5)" },
                borderColor = new string[] { "rgb(54, 162, 235)", "rgb(255, 205, 86)", "rgb(255,99,132)" },
                borderWidth = "1"
            });
            _chart.datasets = _dataSet;
            return Json(_chart, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

And in your view script used data in this way:

```
 jQuery.extend({
            getValues: function (url) {
                var result = null;
                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    type: 'get',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        result = data;
                    }
                });
                return result;
            }
        });
```